# Why my component is not changing state when I trigger the function

Tags: reactjs

I am in new in React and I am trying to change the state when the user type some values in the inout. For a reason the component does not seem to work. Could anyone explain me why I am not succeeding in implementing this function? Thanks, Valentino

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Stake extends Component {
    state = ({
        userStake: null
    });

    handleUserStake = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newStake = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            userStake: [...userStake, newStake]
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleUserStake}>
                    <input
                        style={{
                            marginLeft: "40px",
                            width: "50px"
                        }}
                        type="text"
                        name="stake"
                        required
                    />
                </form>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default Stake;
```

Comment: By not working, do you mean the value is not displayed in the text field after you hit enter?

Comment: I get 'userStake' is not defined

Comment: Just do `userStake:newStake` in your handler, and add an `onChange={handleUserStake}` in input field

Comment: I wanted to add the new input in the array that is why I wrote userStake: [...userStake, newStake]. How can I create an array with old and newstake?thanks

Comment: I think the main problem is you don't understand well how to make react class component: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html then read https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first get userStake from the state

```
handleUserStake = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newStake = e.target.value;
    // you need to first get it from the state before updating
    const { userStake } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        userStake: [...userStake, newStake]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to accomplish a controlled input you should add the property `value` pointing to the respective state, and `onChange` that will handle its state update. for your `onSubmit` you use another handler specific to it. you should also fix your handleChange to update its  value correctly:

```
class Stake extends Component {
    state = ({
        userStake: [],
        input: ''
    });

    handleUserStake = (e) => {
        let input = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ input });
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newStake = this.state.input;
        this.setState({
            userStake: [...this.state.userStake, newStake],
            input: '',
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        style={{
                            marginLeft: "40px",
                            width: "50px"
                        }}
                        type="text"
                        name="stake"
                        value={this.state.input}
                        onChange={this.handleUserStake}
                        required
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Stake;
```

Comment: Yes, this solution should work.

1) Your input needs an onChange handler
2)  e.target.value will get the value from the textbox, so you can simply assign it to the state variable and no need to use spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create constructor for your component with state and binded `handleUserStakez method.

Because you are waiting for the submit event from form you would use ref for the input:

```
this.inputRef = React.createRef();
ref={this.inputRef}
```

Full code here:

```
class Stake extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userStake: ""
    };
    this.handleUserStake = this.handleUserStake.bind(this);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleUserStake = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newStake = this.inputRef.current.value;
    console.log("newStake", newStake);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      userStake: newStake
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        STATE: {this.state.userStake}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleUserStake}>
          <input
            style={{
              marginLeft: "40px",
              width: "50px"
            }}
            type="text"
            name="stake"
            required
            ref={this.inputRef}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to create a constructor in class components. if you define your function as arrow function it will bind it automatically

Answer (score 0):

this should work ...

```
 state = {
    userStake: [],
  };

  handleUserStake = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newStake = e.target.stake.value;
    this.setState((state) => ({
      userStake: [...state.userStake, newStake],
    }));
  };
```

### what was problem? :-

1. getting value you need to add NAME from `target` which is `form` to get field value. like ...

- `let newStake = e.target.stake.value;`

2. getting current `state` value, your were just getting `userStake` out of nowhere so it was giving `undefined` error.

- `this.setState((state) => ({   userStake: [...state.userStake, newStake], }));`

3. make default value to `[]` for `userStake` in `state` obj.

- `userStake: []`

Comment: I keep getting state is not defined. Also I had to add a comma after (state) due to a warning error

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. The problem was that I had to write [...this.state.userStake, newStake]